# Getting the content of an IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: c#, xna, xmlserializer, monogame

I am trying to create a method to serialize and deserialze a data file but I am running into some errors.

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (10, 10).

Is there a way to get the contents of the data file to see what it could be?

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
    IsolatedStorageFile dataFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
#else
    IsolatedStorageFile dataFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain();
#endif

try
{
    // Create an isolated storage stream and initialize it as null.
    IsolatedStorageFileStream isolatedFileStream = null;
    // Open the isolated storage stream, and write the save data file.
    if (dataFile.FileExists(filename))
    {
        using (isolatedFileStream = dataFile.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            // Read the data from the file.
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
            // Store each of the deserialized data objects in the list.
            Data savedData = (Data)serializer.Deserialize(isolatedFileStream);
```

Comment: have you seen what the xml look like at line 10, column 10?

Comment: No as I am not sure how to view the file?

Comment: By reading the exception I guess that it's an invalid XML file. Try open the file as a text file instead and output somewhere so you can see the content.